Cross Validation for Time Series?
Consider a generic (univariate) time series model:
$$ \hat{y}(x_n, \ldots, x_{n+h-1} \mid x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}; \boldsymbol{\theta}) $$
Where:
$$ \hat{y}_{t+h} \text{ is the forecast for the next } h \text{ time points} $$
$$ \boldsymbol{\theta} = (\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_k) \text{ is the vector of model parameters} $$
$$ x_t, x_{t-1}, \ldots, x_{t-p} \text{ are the } p \text{ most recent observations} $$
The way I see it, there are two ways (Static vs Dynamic) to perform Rolling Window Cross Validation in this setting. I am not sure which one is correct.

Static Approach:


Step 1: Here, we fit a single model (e.g ARIMA) to first $n$ points (i.e. 0 to $n$)
Step 2: Then, we use this model from Step 1 to forecast the next $h$ points (i.e. $n+1$ to $n+h$) in a row (in one shot) and record the error
Step 3: We then give the model the true information all the way to the $n+h$ point and again make it forecast $h$ more points, record the error etc.

Mathematically, we can represent this idea as follows:
$$ \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}} = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \sum_{i=1}^n L(y_i, \hat{y}(x_i \mid x_0, \ldots, x_{i-1}; \boldsymbol{\theta})) $$
For forecasts:
$$ \text{For } t = n, n+h, \ldots, T-h: $$
$$ \hat{y}_{t+h} = \hat{y}(x_{t+h} \mid x_0, \ldots, x_t; \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}) $$
$$ e_{t+h} = y_{t+h} - \hat{y}_{t+h} $$

Dynamic Approach:


Step 1: Here, we fit a model (e.g ARIMA) to first $n$ points (i.e. 0 to $n$)
Step 2: Then, we use this model from Step 1 to forecast the next $h$ points (i.e. $n+1$ to $n+h$) in a row (in one shot) and record the error
Step 3: We re-fit the same type model (e.g. ARIMA) from 0 to $n+h$, and make the model predict again the next $h$ points, etc
Step 4: In the future, we will forecast using the model built on the complete set of data available to us.

Mathematically, we can represent this idea as follows:
$$ \text{For each time step } t = n, n+h, \ldots, T-h: $$
$$ \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}_t = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \sum_{i=t-n+1}^t L(y_i, \hat{y}(x_i \mid x_{t-n+1}, \ldots, x_{i-1}; \boldsymbol{\theta})) $$
$$ \hat{y}_{t+h} = \hat{y}(x_{t+h} \mid x_{t-n+1}, \ldots, x_t; \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}_t) $$
$$ e_{t+h} = y_{t+h} - \hat{y}_{t+h} $$
In both approaches:
$$ L(\cdot) \text{ is a loss function (e.g., squared error)} $$
$$ n \text{ is the size of the initial training window or rolling window} $$
$$ e_{t+h} \text{ is the forecast error} $$
$$ T \text{ is the total number of time points} $$
As we can see,

In the static approach, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$ is computed once using the initial $n$ observations and then used for all subsequent forecasts. The model uses all historical data $(x_0, \ldots, x_t)$ for each forecast. This is computationally more efficient as the model fitting process only happens once. This approach is testing the performance of a "single model". However, I think this approach is less optimal because we only build a model on limited data.

In the dynamic approach, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}_t$ is recomputed at each time step $t$ using the most recent $n$ observations. The model uses only the most recent $n$ observations $(x_{t-n+1}, \ldots, x_t)$ for each forecast. This is computationally less efficient as the model fitting process only happens many times. This approach is testing the performance of a "class of models". However, I think this approach is more robust as it generalizes the idea of the model better. I.e. in the future, how reliable will ARIMA be in general?


I tried to represent my understanding of both approaches visually:

Can someone please tell me which of these approaches is correct?
Thanks!
PS: I also tried to write an R function to represent Approach 2:
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(123)


#n <- 100: length of the time series to 100 observations, it means that the generated time series will have 100 data points.
#h <- 5: T forecast horizon to 5 : model will predict 5 steps ahead in the future. E.g, if the current time point #is ( t ), the model will forecast #the value at ( t+5 ).
#frequency <- 52: This sets the frequency of simulated time series to 52.
#window_size <- 52: size of the rolling window to 52. the model will use the most recent 52 observations to train the model #at each step. E.g.
#if the current time point is ( t ), the model will use the data from ( t-51 ) to ( t ) to make the forecast.

n <- 100
h <- 5
frequency <- 52
window_size <- 52
##################################

time_series <- arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.8), n = n) + 10 + 0.5 * (1:n)

ts_data <- ts(time_series, frequency = frequency)

# Rolling window cross-validation function
rolling_cv <- function(data, h = 1, window_size = 52) {
    n <- length(data)
    forecasts <- numeric(n - window_size - h + 1)
    actual <- numeric(n - window_size - h + 1)
    
    for (i in 1:(n - window_size - h + 1)) {
        train <- data[i:(i + window_size - 1)]
        test <- data[i + window_size + h - 1]
        
        model <- auto.arima(train)
        forecast <- forecast(model, h = h)
        
        forecasts[i] <- forecast$mean[h]
        actual[i] <- test
    }
    
    return(list(forecasts = forecasts, actual = actual))
}

# Perform rolling window cross-validation
cv_results <- rolling_cv(ts_data, h = h, window_size = window_size)

errors <- cv_results$actual - cv_results$forecasts
percent_errors <- 100 * errors / cv_results$actual

plot_data <- data.frame(
    Time = (1:(length(cv_results$actual))) + window_size + h - 1,
    Actual = cv_results$actual,
    Forecast = cv_results$forecasts,
    Error = errors,
    PercentError = percent_errors
)

p1 <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Time)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Actual, color = "Actual")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Forecast, color = "Forecast")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Actual" = "blue", "Forecast" = "red")) +
    labs(title = "Actual vs Forecast", y = "Value") +
    theme_minimal()

p2 <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Time, y = Error)) +
    geom_line(color = "green") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
    labs(title = "Forecast Errors", y = "Error") +
    theme_minimal()

p3 <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Time, y = PercentError)) +
    geom_line(color = "purple") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
    labs(title = "Forecast Percent Errors", y = "Percent Error") +
    theme_minimal()

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1, heights = c(3, 3, 3))

mae <- mean(abs(errors))
rmse <- sqrt(mean(errors^2))
mape <- mean(abs(percent_errors))

cat("Mean Absolute Error:", mae, "\n")
cat("Root Mean Square Error:", rmse, "\n")
cat("Mean Absolute Percentage Error:", mape, "%\n")


